# This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled at minikube - windows 10

Tags: kubernetes, windows-10, virtualbox, minikube

! StartHost failed, but will try again: creating host: create: precreate: This computer doesn't have VT-X/AMD-v enabled. Enabling it in the BIOS is mandatory

I am getting this issue when I am executing the [minikube start --driver=virtualbox] command in my windows machine. I have already enable the VT-X/AMD-v in my machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

minikube start --no-vtx-check

This command create the kubertenes cluster with out any error.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already enabled the feature in the BIOS, make sure you did not enable the Windows Hyper-V feature as well. Otherwise VirtualBox will not run.

Comment: Already disabled the hyper-v feature